# Detect app opening by other app with URL Scheme

Tags: ios, swift, url-scheme

this is my scenery:

i need to show an alert box for customize settings when my app is opened or returned from background by user and another one when my app is opened or returned from background by other app through URL Scheme.

How can i do it?

The notification of openURL arrive later than view did load...

thanks in advance

Comment: Please show your code, what did you try so far that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your app comes back from the background, app delegate events will arrive in this order:

- `applicationWillEnterForeground(_:)`
- `application(_:open:options:)`
- `applicationDidBecomeActive(_:)`

Thus it is easy to know by the time the application becomes active whether this is because of a URL scheme or not.

Comment: thank you for your answer...but when my app is closed and another one want to launching it? How can I do?

Comment: That case is even simpler because `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` will tell you about the URL (in the `options` dictionary).